# Does kubectl rollout restart work for daemonset?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod attached to a daemonset node and which also contains several containers. I want to update the container images inside the pod. Therefore I am curious to know if restarting the the daemonset will do the job (because image Pull Policy is currently set to always) and restarting the daemonset will pull the new updated image. Is it the right way to do such things?
Thanks.

Comment: See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-daemon/update-daemon-set/

Answer (score 2):

Use `kubectl set image -n <namespace> daemonset <ds name> <container name>=<image>:<tag>` will do the trick and does not require restart command.

To see the update status `kubectl rollout status -n <namespace> daemonset <ds name>`

Comment: I am using set image, but it wont update the ds if I keep the image name same as the currrent. But I just need to recreate the containers of the pod.

Comment: You want to perform container restart so you get newer image tagged with **latest** ? In this case, first your spec must set `imagePullPolicy: Always`, then do `kubectl rollout restart daemonset <ds name>`